# Java reflection, call method from superClass?

Tags: java, reflection

I've seen a lot of examples, and I know what has been discussed.
I do everything right, but I receive an error. Why is that? What am i doing wrong?

```
Class superClass = rootObject.getSuperclass();
Method addErrorMethod = superClass.getDeclaredMethod("addErrorMessage", ErrorType.class, String.class, String.class, String.class);
_log.info(addErrorMethod.getName());
addErrorMethod.invoke(superClass, ErrorType.FIELD, propertyName, message, "");
```

I get method, but when you call the invoker. I get the following error.

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

Thanks.

Comment: "I do everything right, but I receive an error." A plea for help?

Comment: yes, Please help. ))

Comment: If you did everything right, you wouldn't be getting an error.

Answer (score 5):

When you call `Method.invoke` the first parameter must be either:

- when method is non-static instance of the class which contains the method
- when method is static `null` or class itself.

Since you pass the class itself and you got error it suggests that method you are trying to invoke is not static, so you should invoke it like

```
addErrorMethod.invoke(rootObject, ErrorType.FIELD, propertyName, message, "");
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^- assuming it is instance on which we want to invoke this method
```

Comment: @JDev No, you pass the class (`superClass`), not the object (`rootObject`)

Comment: "object of the class", not "class of the object"

Comment: @JDev by *object of the class* answerer means instance of class (one you receive by calling constructor), not `SomeType.class` literal.

Comment: The method is in superclass

Comment: @JDev And `rootObject` *is* an instance of the superclass.

Comment: Yes Class<ModelObject> rootObject

Comment: ModelObject is Superclass

Comment: Wero, clarification from [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29): "If the underlying method is static, then the specified `obj` argument is **ignored**. It *may* be null." It doesn't have to be null.

Comment: MyObject extends ModelObject

Comment: @JDev suppose the superclass is java.lang.Number, and you want to call byteValue(). Suppose rootObject is an instance of java.lang.Integer, which extends Number. What you want to call is `rootObject.byteValue()`. So the first argument of `invoke()` must be `rootObject`. If you pass `Number.class` as first argument of `invoke()`, you're asking Java to call `byteValue()` on `java.lang.Class<Number>`.

Comment: @wero I tried to clarify your answer a little. Hope you don't mind my edit (feel free do roll it back if you want)

Comment: Oops, I think we all got confused because of **bad variable naming**. `rootObject.getSuperclass()` implies that `rootObject` is of type **`Class`**. The code doesn't show any *instance* variable name, or where `rootObject` came from, so..... *<shrugs>*

Comment: @Pshemo great, thank you. If JDev just would try it that we can go on to discuss the likely `IllegalAccessException`

Comment: @Andreas time to close the browser for today :-)

Comment: addErrorMethod.invoke(rootObject, ErrorType.FIELD, propertyName, message, "");
So too does not work. The same error.

Comment: @JDev That is because `rootObject` is also `Class<YourType>` but not instance of `YourType`. Try using something more like `YourType instance = new YourType(); method.invoke(instance, restOfArguments);`.

Comment: @JDev Because (as we just realized because you *didn't show us*), `rootObject` is of type `Class`. The first parameter to `invoke` must be a value of type `MyObject` or `ModelObject`.

Comment: I think I already understand where my mistake. Tomorrow will look. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

You did not do everything right:

```
addErrorMethod.invoke(superClass, ErrorType.FIELD, propertyName, message, "");
```

should read

```
addErrorMethod.invoke(rootObject, ErrorType.FIELD, propertyName, message, "");
```

`superClass` is an instance of `Class`, to which has no `addErrorMessage()` method, as the error message is telling you. The first parameter to the method is a reference to the object that will be used as `this` within the method.